# Adding "options" menu in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I add the options menu on right-clicking the icon of a Google Chrome extension?

I have made a file named `options.html`; now how do i link it up so it works? I thought it would be automatic.

Comment: figured it out - 
    "options_page": "options.html",

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Chrome populates the right-click menu automatically, so to have an Options item there your extension needs to actually provide an options page. As you've figured out already, designating `options.html` as your options page is done by adding the following line to `manifest.json`:

```
"options_page": "options.html",
```

See [documentation of this feature](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.html).

Comment: Just wanted to make sure there is a proper answer here.

Comment: And here is a current [documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.html).